# A neat proof that the Lebesgue measure is rigid motion invariant.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I'm busy doing a small undergraduate maths project on the Banach Tarski paradox and I was hoping I could prove that a lebesgue measure is rigid motion invariant but I can't find an eloquent proof online that isn't too long and cumbersome. I need it to be realtively short because I have a word limit and don't want too much of my project to be devoted to proving something that isn't one of the main results. I was wondering if anybody new of a relatively short self contained proof. If this proof works for $\mathbb{R}^3$ only that would be fine.

Comment: Depends on your starting point. If $\phi(x) = Ax+b$, and we define $\tilde{m} S = m(\phi(S))$, then a standard result is that $\tilde{m} S = |\det A| mS$.

Answer (score 2):

As @copper.hat mentions above, you need the fact that any rigid motion of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form
$$
\phi(x) = Ax+b
$$
where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

You also need that the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, and for any invertible matrix $T$,
$$
m(T(E)) = |det(T)|m(E)
$$
Both these proofs can be found in Folland's book (See Theorem 2.4.2, and 2.4.4) on Real Analysis.

Now use the fact that if $A$ is orthgonal, then $|det(A)| = 1$

Comment: Do you mean Follard real analyis: Modern techniques and their application?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: I found a copy of the second editoin online but I can't find those theorems. Maybe you could give me a page number.

Comment: It is in the section titled "n-dimensional Lebesgue integral". Page 71 and 73, in the book I have (which is the second edition, but perhaps yours is a different print)

Comment: Found it thanks